# Only one prop is able to pass the data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

When I try to pass props from one component to another, only one of them receives data. I am not able to get "users" details to AccountabilityChart component.

I am only able to get data props but not users props. What is the issue? I am not able to figure it out the behaviour. Can any one explain why this happens and if their is a way to have both the props

```
    const Card = (props: any) => {
        useEffect(()=>{
           console.log("These are props: ", props);
        }, []);
        const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
        return (
            <ul>
                {props.data.map((item: any, index: any) => (
                    <React.Fragment key={item.name}>
                        <li>
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <p>{item.name}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                        <Select
                                            defaultValue={selectedOption}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            className="select"
                                            options={props.users}
                                        />
                                </div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            {item.children?.length && <Card data={item.children} users={[]} />}
                        </li>
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    };
    
    const AccountabilityChartComponent = () => {
        const [hierarchy, setHierarchy] = useState([]);
        const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            someApiCall.then(
                    function success(results) {
                        setHierarchy(results.entities);
                    }
                );
            someApiCall.then(
                function success(results: any) {
                    setUsers(wrapped);
                }
            );
        }, []);
        return (
            <div className="grid">
                <div className="org-tree">
                    <Card
                        users={users}
                        data={hierarchy}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
export default AccountabilityChartComponent;
```

[Organizational hierarchy I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6nJi.png)

[Console log is called 4 times. It means the state is updated 4 times? Will it effect my performance?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGGQx.png)

Comment: `AccountabilityChartComponent` doesn't appear to use or reference `props` passed to it. Can you clarify what exactly "not able to get `users` prop" means?

Comment: AccountabilityChartComponent are using props in WEBAPI. I have not shown in the code to make it simple. I am passing "users" and "data" as props to Card component. However,  when I console props in Card component I am getting: data: [{…}]
users: []

Comment: `Card` recursively renders another `Card` and only passes an empty array. Is the nested `Card` with empty `users` array what you are seeing?

Comment: Yes I am getting empty users array. But I am only using users array in                                         <Select
defaultValue={selectedOption}
onChange={handleChange}
className="select"
options={props.users}
/>
And I am using as props.users. So does it make any difference if a Card recursively renders another Card and "only passes an empty array of users".?

Comment: @DrewReese I have changed my code to {item.children?.length && <Card data={item.children} users={props.users} />} and it started to show the list of users. However, I am still confused why is it so? I was using props.users value from the top also?

Comment: @DrewReese one more thing if you can help me with. When I created a useEffect(()=>{
console.log("This is props context: ", props);}, []) in Card component. it console it 4 times. Can you please let me know the reason. Is it effecting the performance?

Comment: Hard to say without a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]. Can you edit your post to include a reproducible coffee example. If possible you could also try making a *running* codesanbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: That is likely the React `SrtictMode `component. See https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects and https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the above post. Please let me know is it more understandable? Also I have added 2 images for reference

Comment: I see, well, you are console logging props when the `Card` component mounts, and each log appears to be unique to each separate instance of the `Card` component that is rendered. I don't see anything overtly suspicious there.